# PMF for difference between two random integers sampled from $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find the probability mass function of $X$, $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and var$(X)$.

$$P_X(x) = $$

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n - x} \frac{1}{n(n - 1)}, n + 1 > x > 0$$
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n + x} \frac{1}{n(n - 1)}, -n - 1 < x < 0$$
$$ 0, \text{otherwise}$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{X = 1}^{n} X\sum_{i = 1}^{n - X}\frac{1}{n(n - 1)} + \sum_{X = -1}^{-n} X\sum_{i = 1}^{n + X}\frac{1}{n(n - 1)} $$
$$= \sum_{X = 1}^{n} X\sum_{i = 1}^{n - X}\frac{1}{n(n - 1)} + \sum_{X = 1}^{n} (-X)\sum_{i = 1}^{n - X}\frac{1}{n(n - 1)} = 0$$

$$\text{var}(X) = 2\sum_{X = 1}^{n} X^2\sum_{i = 1}^{n - X}\frac{1}{n(n - 1)}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You're using $X$ as both the random variable and the summation index. That seems unwise.

Comment: No, i am using $X$ and $x$

Comment: Not in what you wrote, you don't.

Comment: Assuming you intended "difference" instead of "absolute difference", then, since the probability of getting $(a,b)$ is the same as the probability of getting $(b,a)$, the expected difference is clearly $0$ without any calculating.

Comment: Oh yeah i understand that. I was just shocked that our professor is asking us to compute this summation in an exam.

Comment: And people asked him if he was asking for absolute difference instead of difference and I suspected that people were thinking absolute would make the problem easier to solve. I was just checking my thoughts. I guess thats what I get for admitting myself into a bad school :'(.